# How can I avoid copy/paste HTML code in different parts of the same page

Tags: html, django-templates, pagination

I want to add a paginator in my page, e.g. using Django

```
{% for contact in page_obj %}
    {# Each "contact" is a Contact model object. #}
    {{ contact.full_name|upper }}<br>
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

I really do not like having to scroll to the bottom of the page to go next, I rather want to be able to switch to next page also from the top.

Instead of copying the same HTML code both at the top and bottom of the page: is there a way to create like a function, which could called from different parts of the HTML page?
That would reduce the size of the page and improve readability.